# Show that $O(n,\mathbb{R})$ the set of all orthogonal matrices is closed in $M(n,\mathbb{R})$

Tags: continuity, metric-spaces

> Show that $O(n,\mathbb{R})$ the set of all orthogonal matrices is closed in $M(n,\mathbb{R})$

Let $$f:M(n,\mathbb{R}) \mapsto \mathbb{R}$$

$$ f:A \mapsto det(A.A^t)$$

We know that $$
\text{det}(x_{i,j})= \sum_\sigma \text{sgn}(\sigma) \prod_{i=1}^{n} x_{\sigma(i),i}
$$
The determinant function is continuous as it is a polynomial function in $x_1,\cdots x_n$. Then  $det(A.A^t)$ is also a polynomial in $x_1,\cdots x_n$ . Any function from $M(n,\mathbb{R})$ to a polynomial in $x_1,\cdots , x_n$ is continuous. So the following map $f$ is continuous.

$O(n,\mathbb{R}) = f^{-1}(\{1\})$.

The singleton $\{1\}$ is a closed set in $\mathbb{R}$. Hence, $O(n,\mathbb{R})$ is a closed set in $M(n,\mathbb{R})$.

> I have not seen any answer in stackexchange similar to this method. Is my procedure incorrect?
> Also can we extend the following method to prove that $SO(n,\mathbb{R})$ is continuous?

Here's my attempt for $SO(n,\mathbb{R})$ I was thinking of the following map $f:M(n,\mathbb{R}) \mapsto \mathbb{R}$ where $A \mapsto det(A).det(A^t)$ . I think that the following map will be continuous but I am not sure whether $f^{-1}(\{1\}) = SO(n,\mathbb{R})$?

Comment: It's not true that $O(n)=f^{-1}(\{1\})$. Take for example $n=2$ and $A=\begin{pmatrix}1/2&0\\0&2\end{pmatrix}$. Then, $A$ is not orthogonal, however $f(A)=1$.

Comment: Go back to the definition of $O(n,\Bbb R)$, the function you will have to use is therein.

Comment: Hint : This function does not necessarily take values in $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: BIG HINT: a matrix is orthogonal if and only if $AA^t=I$ (the identity matrix). Hence the function you need to use should be $$A \mapsto AA^t$$

Comment: The same question has already been asked multiple times.